# Error: Argument 'ContactController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm trying to create a little controller in my simple web app using angularjs but i get this error:

```
Error: Argument 'ContactController' is not a function, got undefined
```

This is what i've done so far:

angular (ContactsController.js):

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.ContactController = ("ContactController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.contatti = {};
    $scope.contatti.contacts = ["test.one@gmail.com", "test.two@gmail.com"];

    $scope.contatti.addContacts = function () {
        $scope.contatti.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.contatti.newcontact = "";
    };

}]);
```

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="mainApp" data-ng-controller="ContactController">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.3.12/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.3.12/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.3.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.3.12/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ukit-2.16.2/css/uikit.almost-flat.css" />
    <script src="ContactsController.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        Email:<input type="text" ng-model="contatti.newcontact" />

        <button ng-click="addContacts()">Add</button>

        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="contact in contatti.contacts"> {{ contact }} </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be like :-

```
mainApp.controller("ContactController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.contatti = {};
    $scope.contatti.contacts = ["test.one@gmail.com", "test.two@gmail.com"];

    $scope.contatti.addContacts = function () {
        $scope.contatti.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.contatti.newcontact = "";
    };

}]);
```

Comment: yeah! It works and you're right. Thanks. By the way not works and not add what i write inside the input text

Comment: Change $scope.newcontact to $scope.contatti.newcontact

Comment: i solved..it was this : <button ng-click="contatti.addContacts()">Add</button> i missed "contatti" before addContacts(). Thanks  :)

Comment: Its better not to use ng app and ng controller in one <div>

Comment: @MANOJ can you explain why ?

Comment: @squiroid If you are using more than one controlller you will find it difficult to incude it in your app

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
mainApp.ContactController = ("ContactController", ["$scope", function($scope)
```

By:

```
mainApp.controller= ("ContactController", ["$scope", function($scope)
```